# Иерархический шаблон wpf

Tags: wpf, .net, wpf-шаблоны

Подскажите, как правильно написать шаблон:
Допустим, я использую EF code first, по таблицам строю дерево:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Item" DataType="{x:Type classes:Item}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Background="Green"/>
</DataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="SubCategory" DataType="{x:Type classes:SubCategories}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Item}">
    <StackPanel Background="Blue">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>            
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Category" DataType="{x:Type classes:Categories}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubCategories}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SubCategory}">
    <StackPanel  Background="Red">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

По такому шаблону строится дерево вида:
Категории - подкатегории - итемы

Как сделать чтобы в подкатегориях были итемы, а также вложенные подкатегории со своими итемами?

Comment: Вам нужно дерево "Категории - подкатегории - итемы - итемы_итемов"?

Comment: Не совсем, чтобы класс с подкатегориями вкладывался сам в себя, т.е. категория - подкатегория - подкатегория, итемы - итемы или другими словами в подкатегории могут быть как итемы, так и другая подкатегория со своими итемами

Comment: Разобрался, все оказывается решается через MultiBinding

Comment: Хорошо. Можете оформить как ответ, будет полезно другим.